# How to efficiently convert byte array to string

Tags: java, byte

I have a byte array of 151 bytes which is typically a record, The record needs to inserted in to a oracle database. In 151 byte of array range from 0 to 1 is a record id , 2 to 3 is an reference id , 4 to 9 is a date value. The following data in an byte array is a date value. i want to convert it to string

```
byte[] b= {48,48,49,48,48,52};  // when converted to string it becomes 10042. 

new String(b);  // current approach
```

is there any way to  efficiently to convert byte array of some range (`Arrays.copyOfRange(b,0,5)`) to string .

Comment: @Martjin i have file which has 527890 bytes and i have to read the chunk of 2048 bytes which has 13 records , each record is 151 bytes , and we have to extract the ranges and store in table columns.;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
new String(b, 0 ,5);
```

See the [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) for more information.

Comment: @Rekin: no, Suresh specifially does NOT want to use the entire byte array. If he did, it would be much simpler: `new String(b)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String(bytes[] bytes, int offset, int length)` constructor: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], int, int)

```
new String(b, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a string for each region in the record, I would suggest a substring approach:

```
byte[] wholeRecord = {0,1,2 .. all record goes here .. 151}
String wholeString = new String(wholeRecord);
String id = wholeString.substring(0,1);
String refId = wholeString.substring(1,3);
...
```

The actual offsets may be different depending on string encoding.

The advantage of this approach is that the byte array is only copied once. Subsequent calls to `substring()` will not create copies, but will simply reference the first copy with offsets. So you can save some memory and array copying time.

Comment: thanks. but u said offset would be different . how to do that dynamically depending upon offset.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here consider that you might not be using ASCII. When converting bytes to a string, you should always consider the charset.

```
new String(bytes, offset, length, charset);
```

Comment: This is the right answer. (But, even worse than ASCII, that other overload uses the _default_ encoding, which varies from time to time, user to user, system to system.)

Answer (score -1):

and here fantastic way (not efficient) :)

```
    byte[] b = { 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 52 };
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);

    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bais));

    String s = buf.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
```