# GWT client side file upload

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom, uibinder

I can upload a file with the HTML element `inputfile` then get the byte stream of this file through `FileReader`. After calling the function `reader.readAsBinaryString(blob)` as shown in the "Slicing a file" example I now need to gain an access to the uploaded bytestream of the file in GWT client code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store the bytes server side then from the GWT client call the server and retrieve the bytes. Most likely through an RPC call.

See [Create Byte Array from GWT File upload Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594783/create-byte-array-from-gwt-file-upload-input)

"For security reasons browsers can't read files from your file system. (You could use a plugin like a flash plugin to get it to work, although I have no examples at hand)."

Answer (score 0):

use File API of GWT Client side, FileUpload Class;

class is in com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload;

BR/